# Current flow and electromagnetic fields

Tags: electromagnetism

In my attempt to reinforce some electromagnetism concepts, I took the fragment below from the book “Right the First Time, A Practical Handbook on High Speed PCB and System Design".

I got confused with the statement: *Current flow is induced by electromagnetic fields. Electromagnetic fields are not induced by current flow.*

To my understanding, current flow through a wire can induce a magnetic field. So it's confusing when the author says that electromagnetic fields are not induced by current flow. Am I mixing some wrong concepts or the statement is not well elaborated?

[image]

Comment: It reads like grade 1 bullshit to me. Current can be said to be “induced” in a capacitor when a changing electric field is applied across its plates and, for a transformer, voltage is induced by the changing magnetic field (in turn due to a changing current in the primary).

Comment: @Andyaka Agreed. The author is confused and obviously hasn't understood well, or at least has grossly distorted them, any related physics concepts.

Comment: I like how the author suggests that it’s not uncommon to struggle because the author is perfectly demonstrating that.

Comment: Fortunately this was the beginning of the book so I just stopped reading it soon and waste time.

Comment: Burn it quickly lol

Comment: @Blue_Electronx I've written elsewhere here on the smaller details of how current is induced in wires at a more "atomic level" view. But I'd recommend that you get and read "Matter & Interactions" by Chabay and Sherwood. Get at least the 3rd edition (a later one if it exists, I suppose.) It's better that you read that book, than read my writing about concepts within in. So I'll only point you to my writing if you want. Otherwise, just get the book. It's targeted at a very accessible level.

Comment: @Blue_Electronx By the way, if you are interested in digging really deeply into those experiments that helped us demonstrate the existence, mass, and charge of the electron as well as how we must understand the quantum level, "Exploring Quantum Physics though Hands-on Projects" by David and Shanni (his daughter) Prutchi, a Wiley pub, is worth getting. It doesn't cost an arm and a leg, anymore, to perform experiments and this book walks you through doing the experiments. I was fortunate. My last year of HS physics had 7 students taught by a M.S in physics from Northwestern U. We did this stuff!

Comment: @jonk Thank you! Your suggestions seem promising, I'll get them. I'm also interested in EMC. Have you heard about the book "Electromagnetic Compatibility Engineering by Henry W. Ott" ? It looks trustworthy.

Comment: @Blue_Electronx I haven't heard of that book, but I know of Henry Ott. He worked at Bell Labs for a while. I think you can rely on what he writes.